# Getting Exception when reorder RowLabel when hiding the Subtotal -Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

As per below code i dont want to add addRowLabel(1) but need addRowLabel(2) . After running the application and open the pivot table its giving exception but if you add addRowLabel(1)(currently commented) its working as expected. This is happening after adding the logic to hide Subtotal. Is this is the expected behaviour of apache POI or It can be fixed?
  Please find the  code below. 
Note: This issue comes when hiding subtotal.

```
  package com.test.pivottables;
  import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
  import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
   import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
     import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.HashSet;
   import java.util.Iterator;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Set;
  import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;
 class TestPivotTables {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    String[][] data = new String[][]{{"STATUS","PASSED","DATA","VALUE"}, 
  {"BLUE","Y","TTT","20"},
 {"RED","N","UUU","10"},{"BLUE","N","PPP","30"}};

    XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("data");
    XSSFSheet pivot = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("summary");
    for(String[] dataRow : data){
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
        for(String dataCell : dataRow){
            XSSFCell cell = 
        row.createCell(row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
            cell.setCellValue(dataCell);
        }
    }

    XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();    
    CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();
    table.setDisplayName("table");
    cttable.setRef("A1:D4");
    cttable.setId(1);

    CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
    columns.setCount(3);

    int i = 1;
    for (String colName : data[0]){
        CTTableColumn column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
        column.setId(++i);
        column.setName(colName);      
    }

    XSSFPivotTable pivotTable =  pivot.createPivotTable(new 
 AreaReference("A1:D4", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007),
new CellReference("A4"), sheet);

    pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
    pivotTable.addRowLabel(2);
    //pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);

    List<Integer> iterList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    iterList.add(0);
    iterList.add(2);
    //iterList.add(1);
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setRowHeaderCaption("Colour");
   for (int j=0;j<iterList.size();j++) {
        CTPivotField ctPivotField = 
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().
  getPivotFieldList().get(iterList.get(j));
        for (i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum()-1; i++) {
            if(ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i)!=null) {
                ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
                ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
            }
        }
        for (i = sheet.getLastRowNum(); i > sheet.getLastRowNum()-2; i--) 
  {
            if(ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i)!=null) {
                ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(i);
            }
        }
        ctPivotField.getItems().setCount(2);

        Set<String> collection = new HashSet<String>();
        int ctr = 0;
        Row row = null;
        Cell cell = null;
        boolean isNull = false;
        do{
            try{
                row = sheet.getRow(ctr);
                cell = row.getCell(0);
                collection.add(cell.toString());
                ctr++;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                isNull = true;
            }
        }while(isNull!=true);
        if(collection!=null && collection.size()>0) {
            Iterator value = collection.iterator(); 
            while (value.hasNext()) { 
                pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().
  getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().
  getCacheFieldList().get(j).getSharedItems().addNewS().
  setV(value.next().toString()); 
            } 
        }
        ctPivotField.setAutoShow(false);
        ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false);
        ctPivotField.setSubtotalTop(false);
        ctPivotField.setSubtotalCaption(null);
        ctPivotField.setCompact(false);
    }
    System.out.println("----end---");
    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 3, "test");

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("pivotsample1.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    wb.close();

}}
```

Comment: We need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Using your provided code, nobody can reproduce your issue without having the data in your Excel sheet. Nobody, at least not I, will creating that sheet manually by guessing the data. So please provide code which creates the data also. And please provide **complete** code. Possible helpers should be able copy->paste->compile->run that provided code.

Comment: HI Axel, Added the updated code which contains excel data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are building the pivot table definition and the pivot cache definition. This must be done because `apache poi` creates as much fields for each row label as rows are in the pivot table data range. This is wrong when special settings shall be made for pivot fields. You try to do that, but you do it wrong.

I cannot go into detail where exactly you go wrong because  that would be too much effort. But what needs to be done is:

For each column which is row label:

- Determine unique labels in that column. This is necessary to build
  the cache.

Then build pivot table and cache.

For each unique label:

- Build pivot field item as numbered item.
- Build a cache definition which has a shared element for this label.

Then remove further items from pivot table definition. But leave **one** default element there, if there should be subtotals. If not, then not.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.List;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

class TestPivotTables {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  String[][] data = new String[][]{
   {"STATUS","PASSED","DATA","VALUE"}, 
   {"BLUE","Y","TTT","20"},
   {"RED","N","UUU","10"},
   {"BLUE","N","PPP","30"}
  };

  XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("data");
  XSSFSheet pivot = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("summary");
  for(String[] dataRow : data){
   XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
   for(String dataCell : dataRow){
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
    cell.setCellValue(dataCell);
   }
  }

  AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("A1:D4", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
  XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivot.createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A4"), sheet);

  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setRowHeaderCaption("Colour");

  List<Integer> iterList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  iterList.add(0);
  iterList.add(2);
  iterList.add(1);

  for (Integer j : iterList) {

   //create row label - apache poi creates as much fields for each as rows are in the pivot table data range
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(j);

   //determine unique labels in column j
   TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
   for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
    uniqueItems.add(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
   }
   System.out.println(uniqueItems);
   
   //build pivot table and cache
   CTPivotField ctPivotField = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(j);
   int i = 0;
   for (String item : uniqueItems) {
    //take the items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/>
    ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
    ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
    //build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items 
    //<sharedItems><s v="BLUE"/><s v="RED"/></sharedItems>
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(j)
     .getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
    i++;
   }

   ctPivotField.setAutoShow(false);
   ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false);
   //ctPivotField.setSubtotalTop(false);
   //ctPivotField.setSubtotalCaption(null);
   ctPivotField.setCompact(false);

   //remove further items
   if (ctPivotField.getDefaultSubtotal()) i++; //let one default item be if there shall be subtotals
   for (int k = ctPivotField.getItems().getItemList().size()-1; k >= i; k--) {
    ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(k);
   }
   ctPivotField.getItems().setCount(i);
   
  }

  System.out.println("----end---");

  pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.COUNT, 3, "test");

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("pivotsample1.xlsx");
  wb.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  wb.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Axel for the solution and detailed explanation.